# ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I want to find FRAUD rate for all features separately then replace this values with features value.
For example, my sample data is in below, then i want to find my Model's fraud rate like STEP1, then i want to replace with Model's value like STEP2.

[image]

My code is below to find this values but it is not working. Error code is below also. Can someone to help me?

```
for i in df2_a.columns:
    grp1 = df2.groupby(i, as_index=False, sort=True, group_keys=True)[['EXT_REFERENCE']].count()
    df3 = df2[df2.FRAUD == 0]
    grp2 = df3.groupby(i, as_index=False, sort=True, group_keys=True)[['EXT_REFERENCE']].count()
    df4 = df2[df2.FRAUD == 1]
    grp3 = df4.groupby(i, as_index=False, sort=True, group_keys=True)[['EXT_REFERENCE']].count()
    grp4 = grp1.merge(grp2, how = 'left', on=i )
    grp5 = grp4.merge(grp3, how = 'left', on=i )
    grp6 = grp5.fillna(0)
    grp6[i+'_New'] = grp5.EXT_REFERENCE / grp5.EXT_REFERENCE_x
    grp7 = grp6.fillna(0)
    grp8 = grp7.drop(['EXT_REFERENCE','EXT_REFERENCE_x','EXT_REFERENCE_y'],axis=1)
    df5 = pd.merge(df2_a, grp8, on=i, how='left')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-225543878353> in <module>
  6     grp3 = df4.groupby(i, as_index=False, sort=True, group_keys=True)[['EXT_REFERENCE']].count()
  7     grp4 = grp1.merge(grp2, how = 'left', on=i )
----> 8     grp5 = grp4.merge(grp3, how = 'left', on=i )
  9     grp6 = grp5.fillna(0)
 10     grp6[i+'_New'] = grp5.EXT_REFERENCE / grp5.EXT_REFERENCE_x

/opt/anaconda/envs/env_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in merge(self, right, 
how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
6866                      right_on=right_on, left_index=left_index,
6867                      right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
-> 6868                      copy=copy, indicator=indicator, validate=validate)
6869 
6870     def round(self, decimals=0, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/anaconda/envs/env_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, 
right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, 
validate)
 45                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
 46                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
 ---> 47                          validate=validate)
 48     return op.get_result()
 49 

/opt/anaconda/envs/env_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in 
__init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, 
suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
531         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce
532         # to avoid incompat dtypes
--> 533         self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
534 
535         # If argument passed to validate,

/opt/anaconda/envs/env_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in 
_maybe_coerce_merge_keys(self)
978                       (inferred_right in string_types and
979                        inferred_left not in string_types)):
--> 980                     raise ValueError(msg)
981 
982             # datetimelikes must match exactly

ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should 
use pd.concat
```

***EDIT***

Thanks for you comments guys but i am wondering that, my sample has a just 1 feature cuz it is an example. But in my reel data i have 120 features. So i am trying with 'for loop' in my code for calculate for all columns. Can you please check below example and don't think just 2 feature (Model, age). Think for 120 feature to same calculation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Model': ['audi', 'audi', 'bmw', 'bmw', 'ford', 'ford'],'Age':[1,2,1,2,1,2] , 'Fraud': [1,1,0,0,1,0]})

# group df by Age
grouped_age = df.groupby('Age', as_index=False).mean()
merged_df = pd.merge(df, grouped_age, on=['Age'], how='inner')
df = merged_df.rename({'Age': 'x', 'Fraud_x': 'Fraud', 'Fraud_y':'Age'}, axis='columns')
df = df.drop('x', axis=1)

# group df by Model
grouped_df = df.groupby('Model', as_index=False).mean()
merged_df = pd.merge(df, grouped_df, on=['Model'], how='inner')
# some display corrections
df = merged_df.rename({'Model': 'x', 'Fraud_x': 'Fraud', 'Fraud_y':'Model', 'Age_x':'Age'}, axis='columns')
df = df.drop(['x', 'Age_y'], axis=1)
df = df[['Model', 'Age', 'Fraud']]
df['Model'] = df['Model'] * 100
df['Age'] = (df['Age'] * 100).round(0)
```

**Output:**

```
   Model   Age  Fraud
0  100.0  67.0      1
1  100.0  33.0      1
2    0.0  67.0      0
3    0.0  33.0      0
4   50.0  67.0      1
5   50.0  33.0      0
```

Comment: I added edit in my comment. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your code, but here how I would do it:

```
for col in df.iloc[:, :-1]:
    group_df = df.groupby(col).mean()*100
    df[col] = df[col].map(group_df['Fraud'])
```

Result

```
    Model   Age         Fraud
0   100.0   66.666667   1
1   100.0   33.333333   1
2   0.0     66.666667   0
3   0.0     33.333333   0
4   50.0    66.666667   1
5   50.0    33.333333   0
```

It assumes the Fraud col will be the last col

Comment: I added edit in my comment. Can you please check it?